# GridLines for a coordinate system with a particular basis

Tags: graphics, linear-algebra

Suppose that I use the vectors $(2,1)$ and $(-1,1)$ as a basis for $R^2$.

```
   gr = Graphics[{
   InfiniteLine[{{0, 0}, {2, 1}}],
   InfiniteLine[{{0, 0}, {-1, 1}}],
   Blue, Thick,
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, {2, 1}}],
   Arrow[{{0, 0}, {-1, 1}}],
   Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(v\), \(1\)]\)", {2.2, 0.7}],
   Text["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(v\), \(2\)]\)", {-1.3, 0.7}]
   }, PlotRange -> 6,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> None,
  GridLines -> {Range[-6, 6], Range[-6, 6]}]
```

which produces this plot:

[image: basis vectors]

What would be the simplest way to add grid lines for the system based on $v_1$ and $v_2$? That is, lines parallel to $v_1$ spaced by increments equal to the length of $v_2$, and lines parallel to $v_2$ spaced by increments equal to the length of $v_1$, using a color different from the existing colors?

**Update:** Very nice answer by J.M. `Mesh -> 20` didn't work, but `Mesh -> 19` did.

```
pp = ParametricPlot[{x, y}.{{2, 1}, {-1, 1}}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 
   10}, BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> 19, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed], PlotStyle -> None];

Show[gr, pp]
```

which produced this image.

[image: using ParametricPlot]

**Second Update:** Just tried J.M.'s `AffineTransform` suggestion:

```
v1 = {2, 1}; v2 = {-1, 1};
B = Transpose[{v1, v2}];
{xmin, xmax} = {-10, 10};
{ymin, ymax} = {-10, 10};
Graphics[{
  GeometricTransformation[{
    {Directive[Opacity[0.3, Red], Dashed], 
     Table[InfiniteLine[{0, k}, {1, 0}], {k, ymin, ymax}]},
    {Directive[Opacity[0.3, Red], Dashed], 
     Table[InfiniteLine[{k, 0}, {0, 1}], {k, xmin, xmax}]}},
   AffineTransform[B]]
  },
 PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}},
 GridLines -> {Range[xmin, xmax], Range[ymin, ymax]},
 Axes -> True]
```

which produced this image:

[image: using AffineTransform]

Comment: Something like `ParametricPlot[{x, y}.{{2, 1}, {-1, 1}}, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> 20, MeshStyle -> Black, PlotStyle -> None]`?

Comment: @J.M. Wonderful answer.

Comment: @J.M. That's neat and not obvious.  Why not post an Answer? :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am writing this answer only to address the Wizard's comment of "not obvious". Recall that if you take two nonzero vectors $\mathbf v_1$ and $\mathbf v_2$ as your basis, you can then represent any other vector as a linear combination of these two ($x \mathbf v_1 + y \mathbf v_2$).

In *Mathematica*, this is equivalent to the expression `Transpose[{v1, v2}].{x, y}`, or more compactly `{x, y}.{v1, v2}` (recalling the properties of the dot product in *Mathematica*). (For those of a more geometric bent, look up [`AffineTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AffineTransform.html) as well.)

So, to distort an integer lattice, one can then use [`ParametricPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html), as in my comment above, or use [`InfiniteLine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InfiniteLine.html) again to display the image of the integer lattice under your basis change:

```
v1 = {2, 1}; v2 = {-1, 1};
{xmin, xmax} = {-10, 10};  {ymin, ymax} = {-10, 10};
Graphics[{{Directive[Opacity[0.3, Red], Dashed], 
           Table[InfiniteLine[{0, k}, {1, 0}], {k, ymin, ymax}]},
          {Directive[Opacity[0.3, Red], Dashed], 
           Table[InfiniteLine[{k, 0}, {0, 1}], {k, xmin, xmax}]}} /. 
         v_ /; VectorQ[v, NumericQ] :> v.{v1, v2}, 
         PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}]
```

[image: skewing a lattice]

Additionally, if you only want to see the image of the lattice points under the change of basis, you can use [`CoordinateBoundsArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoordinateBoundsArray.html) like so:

```
Graphics[{Directive[ColorData[97, 3], AbsolutePointSize[6]], 
          Point[#.{v1, v2} & /@ 
          Flatten[CoordinateBoundsArray[{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}], 1]]}, 
         PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}}]
```

[image: lattice points after a basis change]

Comment: I edited your post to include documentation links.  If you prefer that I *not* do this again please let me know and I shall try to remember.

Comment: Oh, it's fine with me. Thanks for taking the trouble.

Comment: @J.M. This is also an amazing example. I learned a lot from this example. Much appreciated.

Comment: @J.M. Just gave your AffineTransform suggestion a try. See my second update to my original post up above. This might work best for my students in linear algebra next fall.

Comment: I've seen it, @David; nicely done!

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT**

My original post was unnecessarily complex (pun?) and I have taken the advice of Kuba.

This is not really an advance but I post it for fun:

```
v1 = {2, 1};
v2 = {-1, 1};
f[x_, y_] := {x, y}.{v1, v2};
Manipulate[
 Row[{Show[Plot[{x, x^2, 5 Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}], 
    ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, 
     MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #4 &}, 
     Mesh -> {Range[0, 5], Range[0, 5]}, Epilog -> Dynamic@Point[p]], 
    ImageSize -> 300], 
   ParametricPlot[{f[x, y], f[x, x], f[x, x^2], f[x, 5 Sin[x] ]}, {x, 
     0, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {-5, 10}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #4 &}, Mesh -> {Range[0, 5], Range[0, 5]},
     Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Dynamic@Point[f @@ p]}, 
    ImageSize -> 300, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]}], {p, {0, 0}, {5,
    5}, Locator}]
```

[image]

...and I am off to sleep:)

Comment: @Kuba thanks for the good advice...:)

Comment: Very nice visualization! (+1 of course.)

Comment: Consider adding `RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, u, v}, RegionMember[Parallelogram[{0, 0}, 5 {v1, v2}], {x, y}]]`

Comment: @J.M. Good advice as always, thank you.