# Sketch the dual lattice $\Gamma^*$?

Tags: graphics

In the book *Eigenvalues in Riemannian Geometry* of Isaac Chavel page $28$ - $29$, they talk about the *lattice* $\Gamma$  and it is defined as $$\Gamma = \left\{\sum_{j=1}^n \alpha^j v_j : \alpha^j \in \mathbb{Z}, j=1,\dots, n\right\}.$$ If I take the canonical basis (simplifying the problem) $v_1=(1,0)$, $v_2=(0,\sqrt{2})$, then I obtain $\Gamma=\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0  \\
  0 & \sqrt{2}  
 \end{pmatrix}\mathbb{Z}^2$. Now, it is possible to associate to the lattice $\Gamma,$ the *dual lattice*, $\Gamma^*$, given by $$\Gamma^*=\{y \in \mathbb{R}^n : \langle x,y\rangle \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ for all } x \in \Gamma\}.$$

**Questions :** Does it exist a way to interpret the dual lattice $\Gamma^*$ graphically, a sketch? How should we interpret this concept in the resolution of the spectrum on the torus?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Just to make sure, this is a question about how to sketch this specifically with the software *Mathematica*, right?

Comment: Yes, but I don't have any experience with this software. I'd like a sketch to better understand the concept of dual lattice $\Gamma^*$ in correspondence with his lattice $\Gamma$

Comment: What have you tried. Please post the code and point out where you're having issues.

Comment: I'll wait if someone know the subject, and yes, $\langle x,y \rangle$ is the usual inner product

Comment: You could do an inversion of an associated matrix, as noted [here](https://www.cims.nyu.edu/~regev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/DualLattice.pdf). After that, you can adapt my solution [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115972).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do the visualization. It is some sort of brute force, direct application of the definitions.

Define lattice $\Gamma$ generation vectors:

```
v1 = {1, 0};
v2 = {0, Sqrt[2]};
```

Generate some $\Gamma$ points:

```
With[{c = 6}, 
  points = Flatten[Outer[#1 v1 + #2 v2 &, Range[-c, c], Range[-c, c]], 1]];
```

Make a "dual lattice point finder" function:

```
ls = LinearSolve[{v1, v2}];
```

Find dual lattice $\Gamma^*$ points by complete enumeration of a subset of $\mathbb{Z}$:

```
With[{c = 10}, 
  dualPoints = 
   ls /@ Flatten[Outer[List, Range[-c, c], Range[-c, c]], 1]];
```

Verify according to definition that the points belong to $\Gamma^*$:

```
Tally[Map[And @@ Map[IntegerQ, points.#] &, dualPoints]]
(* {{True, 441}} *)
```

Plot the points from both lattices:

```
ListPlot[{points, dualPoints}, 
 PlotStyle -> {{PointSize[0.02]}, {PointSize[0.012]}},
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 PlotLegends -> {"\[CapitalGamma]", 
   "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(\[CapitalGamma]\), \(*\)]\)"}]
```

[image]

Comment: `CoordinateBoundsArray[]` would be useful here.

Comment: @J.M. I did not know that function. I was thinking to justify not using it with "I am trying to be more didactic in my answer," but I realized I am not sure what someone with math background, but new to Mathematica would prefer: solutions with a small set of core functions, or solutions with minimal code that is clear from the function names what it does.