# Translate graphics from a contour plot to tile a plane

Tags: plotting, geometric-transform

**MWE:**

```
a = {3, Sqrt[3]}/2;
b = {3, -Sqrt[3]}/2;
W = Parallelogram[{0, 0}, {a, b}];

img = ContourPlot[Sqrt[x^2 + 5 Cos[x^2 y]]^2, {x, y} ∈ W, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

This produces the contour plot of some given function over the region `W`, which is defined as the primitive unit cell of the Bravais lattice spanned by lattice vectors `a` and `b`, seen here:

```
Show[
ContourPlot[Sqrt[x^2 + 5 Cos[x^2 y]]^2, {x, y} ∈ W, 
AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{-2, 5}, {-2, 2}}],
Graphics[{Green, Arrow[{(a + b)/2, (a + b)/2 + a}]}],
Graphics[{Magenta, Arrow[{(a + b)/2, (a + b)/2 + b}]}]
]
```

I wish to produce a plot in which I show several copies of this contour plot, tiled at locations given by small-integer multiples of the lattice vectors.
In other words, **how can I translate my contourplot by vector `a` and show it in the same plot region as the original, with the axes shown?**

I have tried many things related to `GeometricTransformation` but without success. Such as

```
trans = GeometricTransformation[img, TranslationTransform[a]]  

Show[img, trans]
```

etc.

Comment: Try this: `trans =. img /. GraphicsComplex[xs__] :> 
  GeometricTransformation[GraphicsComplex[xs], 
   TranslationTransform[a]]; Show[img, trans, PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {-2, 2}}]`

Comment: That doesn't work for me

Comment: That's because there was a typo. Change `trans =. img ...` to `trans = img ...` (there was an extra `.`).

Comment: [A related thread.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115935)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `GeometricTransformation` only works on `GraphicsPrimitives`, we take advantage of the fact that the default expression-form of figures involve `GraphicsComplex`es and that those are primitives:

```
Show[Table[img /.
     With[{n = n, m = m}, 
       GraphicsComplex[xs__]
        :> GeometricTransformation[GraphicsComplex[xs], TranslationTransform[n a + m b]]
      ],
      {n, -2, 2}, {m, -2, 2}],
   PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works well for me and is mostly transparent. Can you elaborate on the `xs__` argument? Specifically, you use two "_". I assume you are somehow pointing it to go inside `img`, which is a plot, and find all the `GraphicComplex`es, but how did you know to do this in this way?

Answer (score 3):

Figuring out the mechanism behind the following is left as an exercise for the interested reader:

```
With[{a = {3, Sqrt[3]}/2, b = {3, -Sqrt[3]}/2}, 
     ContourPlot[Function[{x, y}, Sqrt[x^2 + 5 Cos[x^2 y]]^2] @@
                 (Mod[LinearSolve[Transpose[{b, a}], {x, y}], 1].{b, a}),
                 {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]]
```

[image: tiles]