# How to create a plot with inclined axes?

Tags: plotting

How can I create a plot with inclined axes?
I want to get something like that:

[image: Plot]

Comment: Perhaps GeometricTransformation?

Comment: [A related question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115935)

Comment: maybe put a 2d plot in 3d space and rotate  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77039/combining-2d-slices-into-a-3d-plot?s=1|0.6473

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my 2nd answer, which uses `Graphics` instead of `Image`.  This approach allows us to manipulate individual graphics elements, which is necessary to rotate the grid lines but not the text.  Thanks to @LLlAMnYP for `GeometricTransformation` and to @J.M. for `ShearingMatrix`.  The trick to using `GeometricTransformation` is to apply `FullGraphics` first.

So first we generate define 2 shearing matrices.  One is the inverse of the other.  Then we generate some data and build a plot using `Line`, `Graphics` and `FullGraphics`.  The `PlotRangeClipping` option is not work for me, so I had to select only the data points that fit in the plot range.  The baseline graphics is called `gfx` and the last command in this section extracts all of the text from `gfx` as the variable `glabels`.

```
θ = π/6;
left = ShearingMatrix[-θ, {1, 0}, {0, 1}];
right = ShearingMatrix[θ, {1, 0}, {0, 1}];
data1 = Table[{x, 0.01/x^3.1 + 0.1}, {x, 0.1, 5, .01}];
data1 = Select[data1, #[[2]] < 5 &];
data1[[;; 10]]
data2 = Table[{x, 0.03/x^3 + 0.2}, {x, 0.1, 5, .01}];
data2 = Select[data2, #[[2]] < 5 &];
data3 = Table[{x, 0.05/x^2.9 + 0.3}, {x, 0.1, 5, .01}];
data3 = Select[data3, #[[2]] < 5 &];
gfx = FullGraphics@Graphics[{
    {Blue, Line[data1]},
    {Red, Line[data2]},
    {Green, Line[data3]}
    }, Frame -> True,
   PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}},
   PlotRangeClipping -> True,
   GridLines -> {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}
   ]
glabels = Cases[gfx, Text[___, ___, ___], Infinity];
```

[image]

Okay, now we are ready to shear the plot over to the left.  But, we do not want to shear the text.  So, we shear the `glabels` to the right, substitute those in for the original labels, and then shear the whole thing to the left.  The substitution is done using a list of rules called `grules`.  The sheared graphics is called `sfx`.  These graphics contain the original gridline labels, but the gridlines are skewed to the left.

```
grules = Thread[Rule[#, GeometricTransformation[#, right]]] & /@ 
   glabels;
sfx = GeometricTransformation [#, left] & /@ (gfx /. grules)
slabels = Cases[sfx, Text[___, ___, ___], Infinity];
```

[image]

The x-axis labels are okay, but the y-axis labels must be translated, as opposed to sheared, over to the left.  We define a function that will take the `Text` and a `ShearingMatrix` and produce a rule that translates the text, only if the text is a y-axis label.  The 3rd argument of the `Text` function, called the offset, is used to distinguish the labels.  If the offset is `{0,1}`, it is an x-axis label so do nothing.  If the offset is `{1,0}`, it is a y-axis label, so translate apply the matrix transform to both the text coordinates and the offset.  Here is the function definition:

```
mkRules[t_: Text, mat_] := 
 Block[{x = t[[1]], y = t[[2]], z = t[[3]]},
  Switch[1,
   Round[z.{0, 1}], Nothing[],
   Round[z.{1, 0}], Rule[t, Text[t[[1]], mat.t[[2]], mat.t[[3]]]]
   ]
  ]
```

We apply the function to make a list of rules for translating the `slabels` to get a list called `srules`.  Then we apply `srules` to `sfx`, which gives the final product.

```
srules = mkRules[#, left] & /@ slabels;
afx = sfx /. srules
```

[image]

Voilà!  The graph is sheared and the text is not.  Thanks again to all commenters and other answers that led to this solution.

Comment: Regarding `FullGraphics[]`, see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/83648).

Answer (score 7):

This approach duplicates some of the features of your example.

```
plt = Plot[{1/x, 2/x, 5/x}, {x, 0, 20}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-10, 20}, Automatic},
   GridLines -> Automatic, Frame -> False];
img = Image[plt];
ImagePerspectiveTransformation[img, {{1, -Sin[π/6]}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

Some of the sheared image is cut off.  To fix that, you might be able to pad the image or insert it onto a larger blank canvas.  There may be ways to mitigate the other drawbacks of this approach.

Comment: Have a look at `ImagePerspectiveTransformation[Plot[{1/x, 2/x, 5/x}, {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> {{-10, 20}, Automatic}, GridLines -> Automatic] // Rasterize, ShearingMatrix[-π/6, {1, 0}, {0, 1}], Background -> White, Masking -> All, PlotRange -> All]`.

Comment: Your solution is good, but axes labels are transformed also =(

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure what the ultimate aim is here. I post this for illustration. Perhaps, it will motivate OP.

```
f[e1_, e2_, p_] := With[{m = Transpose[{e1, e2}]},
  m.p]
vis[e1_, e2_, s_] := 
 Module[{fun = f[e1, e2, #] &, r = Range[-1, 1, 0.1]}, 
  Graphics[{Red, Point[Table[fun@{i, i^2}, {i, -1, 1, s}]], Blue,
    Line[{fun@{-1, #}, fun@{1, #}}] & /@ r,
    Line[{fun@{#, -1}, fun@{#, 1}}] & /@ r}]]
Manipulate[
 Show[vis[v1, v2, 0.01], PlotLabel -> Transpose[{v1, v2}], 
  PlotRange -> 2, GridLines -> gridlines, GridLinesStyle -> Gray],
 {{v1, {1, 0}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}}, {{v2, {0, 1}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}},
 {gridlines, {None, Table[Range[-1, 1, 0.1], 2]}, 
  ControlType -> Checkbox}, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

not exactly the same but perhaps useful

```
Graphics3D[
 First@Cases[Normal@ContourPlot[y^2 == a*x, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -2, 2}], 
   Line[x_] :> {Line[Append[#, 0] & /@ x]}, Infinity], 
 Axes -> {True, True, False}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
 FaceGrids -> {{0, 0, -1}}, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]