# How to Plot with non-orthogonal axes?

Tags: plotting

Sometimes I would want to `Plot` simple functions on unconventional projection, but without specifying all the styling myself. If one looks at `InputForm` of a normal plot, all this would appear to be deep magic. Although on more complex scenarios I would want more than an affine projection, it is also a good starting point. Unfortunately even that with sensible grid lines and ticks labelling seems to be painful with the kludge I have found (yes, arguments are pretty arbitrary in my example):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{t, TriangleWave[t/4], 0}, {t, 0, 10}, 
 FaceGrids -> {{0, 0, 1}}, Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, None},
 ViewMatrix ->
  {TransformationMatrix[
    RescalingTransform[{{-8, 12}, {-2, 12}, {-1, 1}}]],
   {{1, -1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}}},
 PlotRegion -> {{0, 1}, {0, 8/2}}]
```

> [image]

Are there any more sensible approaches to this without generating all the details explicitly?

Comment: The hacky method I use is to convert the result of e.g. `Plot[]` to an image, and then use `Image(Forward)Transformation[]` on it.

Comment: @J.M. I forgot to mention that slanted text is not necessarily a feature I'm looking for... ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a plot with inclined axes?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128427/how-to-create-a-plot-with-inclined-axes)

Comment: @MarcoB Unfortunately "not really" - large portion of the work needs to be done explicitly and `FullGraphics` featured there has serious bit rot that would need to be worked around... but it's good to link here anyway.